# Neo4j: batch iterate options for non-update statements

Tags: loops, csv, neo4j

i have an input CSV file with ~100k-200k records, which will be the source for the set of cypher/match statements the results should be either returned in the browser/exported to CSV.

due to the large number of rows/inputs, for performance reasons, i would like to batch and iterate the input csv rows and return. however, batch & iterate options are mostly available only for "update statements" and not for "return".

the "apoc.periodic.iterate" works only with "set/update".
the "apoc.export.csv.query" doesn't iterate.

any suggestions please ?

### the code looks something like this:-

```
load csv with headers from "file:///sample_i.csv" as row 
with row.a_uuid as a_uuid limit 100
match (ia:Account) where ia.uuid = a_uuid 
with ia
 match p=(pattern_here)
with pattern
match p1=(another pattern)..

return set of attributes
```

---

Comment: did you go through this [blog](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_load_csv_for_medium_sized_datasets) and used PERIODIC COMMIT?

Comment: @ShaikRizwana - yes I did. unfortunately that works for the 'updates only' :(

Comment: Did you try Merge in place of MATCH? As Merge (if found Matches, if not Creates).

Comment: Use some sort of scripting language to batch and save results to a file as you do not want to return 100k+ results to neo4j browser... probably will just crash